# Space between footer and content

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to remove the space between my content and the footer.  Still learning to use HTML so any help will be appreciated.

```css
#foot {
  width: 1536px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #800000;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML as well?

Comment: What ccs are you using for the content id? edit: I don't mean put as an answer.. I am using mobile application.. never used before. Was trying to remove it

Comment: share your whole code

Comment: Hey can you please add the HTML code for your content which you want to be separated from footer?

Answer (score 1):

Hey just saw your HTML and I think I understand your problem now, You want your Content and Footer to have no space at all right? The reason it gets a space after adding a H1 element is that H1 element by default has a margin property.
You can override that by giving it 0 margin in CSS

```
h1 {
  margin:0px   
}
```

Check out this fiddle to see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/6fuk2g8d/1/
Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there I'm still new at this too, but maybe this is what you meant.

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>
  CONTENT
  </h1>
</div>
<footer>
  <h1>
  FOOTER
  </h1>
</footer>
```

```css
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
 footer {
    padding: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-21px);
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

please check this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gyptzxev/

I see that at first after putting an `h1` element inside a footer make the space between `div` content. so in css I put `transform: translateY(-21px);` and the space between is gone. Still I know there are better ways to do this.